# Calculating light intensity in a closed world

Tags: algorithm, math

I am building a simulation in which there is world made of many squares. There are also objects designated as "suns", which illuminate the squares and update their "received intensity" each step.

For example:
[image]

In this image, the distance between the centres of squares is 32 units, and the received intensity (or **R.I.**) of each square is calculated with this formula:

> R.I. = 100 / (distance between light source and square)^2

Written in a generic(and terrible) programming language, a function that calculates R.I. may look like this:

```
(define (calc-RI sq-x sq-y sn-x sn-y)
    (return (/ 100 
               (+ (square (- sq-x sn-x)) 
                  (square (- sq-y sn-y))
               )
            )
    )
)
```

...and, to accommodate multiple suns, the R.I. for each sun will be calculated separately and added together for each square.  This is all well and good, until I felt the need to introduce a **warping mechanic** to this simulation: objects that move "outside" the edge of the world will "re-enter" the world from the other side, like in the game Asteroid.
This not only need to apply to other objects in the simulation, but also light.
[image]
So, what should the new function be for calculating the R.I. of each square? (Given that the function takes in the **x** and **y** coordinate of one square and one sun, and the **width** and **height** of the world, what would be the return of the given square's R.I. under the sun's influence?)

Comment: I noticed that in a closed world, light would "wrap" indefinitely over the edges, but since it weakens every time it warps, we only need to consider the intensity after one "warping"

Comment: If this is about doing at most one warping of the light-ray, it's pretty simple to achieve, as each square gets hit by five "rays": the direct connection, warping around the right edge of the field, warping around the left edge of the field, etc.. Just bruteforce-calculate the value. Otherwise you've basically opened up the Box of Pandora, since an answer would end as a monstrous amount of calculations. In that case: computer graphics is about one thing most of the time: approximations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by imagining that the grid is surrounded by copies of the original grid, one layer for each wrap. For each square in the original grid, calculate the light intensity that falls on each corresponding square, and sum the results.

[image]

In the above diagram, the black grid represents the world, and the blue grid represents the copies of the world grid. To find the light intensity for one wrap at the green square, add the simple intensities calculated at each of the blue squares to the simple intensity calculated for the green square. To calculate another wrap, add another layer of copies.

Here is some Lua code that implements this. Stars are represented in tables of the form:

```
stars = { { x=x1, y=y1 }, { x=x2, y=y2 },... }
```

In this implementation, a square containing a star is given an intensity of `-1`. This could be changed so that a square containing a star accumulates intensity like any other square. To use the functions, define a `stars` table, and call `light_universe()` with the `grid_size` (grids are taken to be square here), `square_size`, `stars` table, and number of `wraps` desired. Set `wraps` to zero, `nil`, or just omit this parameter, to obtain simple intensity calculations with no wrapping. The function `light_universe()` returns a table containing intensities for each square of the world grid. You can view the results by calling `show_intensities()` with the table returned from `light_universe()`, and the `grid_size` of the table. Note that the upper-left corner of the world grid has coordinate (1, 1).

The `calculate_intensity()` function first calculates the `field_size` of the field of grid copies. This is the size of the blue grid in the diagram, and is an odd multiple of `grid_size`, e.g., for 1 wrap the `field_size` is 3. Next, the world coordinates of the current `star` are transformed to the field coordinates `star_x` and `star_y` (the coordinates with respect to the blue grid in the diagram). Then the locations within the field corresponding to `x` and `y` are iterated over. These are the locations of the blue squares of the diagram. The first location is in the upper-left grid of the field, and has field coordinates that are equal to the world coordinates of the square of interest. For each location, the intensity is calculated and added to the running total, which is returned when the iteration is complete.

```
-- Intensity calculation with wraps
-- wraps = nil or wraps = 0 for simple calculation
function calculate_intensity(star, x, y, grid_size, square_size, wraps)
   wraps = wraps or 0
   local field_size = grid_size * (2 * wraps + 1)      -- odd number of grids
   local star_x = star.x + wraps * grid_size           -- cdts of star in field
   local star_y = star.y + wraps * grid_size
   local intensity = 0
   -- x and y are cdts wrt world grid, but also wrt first grid in field
   for field_y = y, field_size, grid_size do
      for field_x = x, field_size, grid_size do
         local dx = square_size * (star_x - field_x)
         local dy = square_size * (star_y - field_y)         
         local dist_sq = dx * dx + dy * dy
         intensity = intensity + 100 / dist_sq
      end
   end
   return intensity
end

function light_universe(grid_size, square_size, stars, wraps)
   wraps = wraps or 0
   local grid_intensities = {}
   for i, star in ipairs(stars) do
      for y = 1, grid_size do
         grid_intensities[y] = grid_intensities[y] or {}
         for x = 1, grid_size do
            if x == star.x and y == star.y then
               grid_intensities[y][x] = -1
            elseif grid_intensities[y][x] ~= -1 then
               grid_intensities[y][x] = (grid_intensities[y][x] or 0) +
                  calculate_intensity(star, x, y, grid_size, square_size, wraps)
            end
         end
      end
   end
   return grid_intensities
end

function show_intensities(grid, grid_size)
   for y = 1, grid_size do
      for x = 1, grid_size do
         local intensity = grid[y][x]
         local fmt
         if intensity ~= -1 then
            fmt = (string.format("%10.5f", intensity))
         else
            fmt = string.format("%-10s", "   Star")
         end
         io.write(fmt)
      end
      print()
   end
end
```

Here is an interaction showing intensity with no wraps, corresponding to the example from your question.

```
> stars = { { x=1, y=1 } }
> light_grid = light_universe(3, 32, stars, 0)
> show_intensities(light_grid, 3)
   Star      0.09766   0.02441
   0.09766   0.04883   0.01953
   0.02441   0.01953   0.01221
```

Here is the same situation with one wrap:

```
> light_grid = light_universe(3, 32, stars, 1)
> show_intensities(light_grid, 3)
   Star      0.17054   0.16628
   0.17054   0.12440   0.12023
   0.16628   0.12023   0.11630
```

And with two wraps:

```
> light_grid = light_universe(3, 32, stars, 2)
> show_intensities(light_grid, 3)
   Star      0.20497   0.20347
   0.20497   0.15960   0.15811
   0.20347   0.15811   0.15664
```

Here is a 7X7 grid with two stars, and one wrap:

```
> stars = { { x=1, y=1 }, { x=7, y=4 } }
> light_grid = light_universe(7, 32, stars, 1)
> show_intensities(light_grid, 7)
   Star      0.13085   0.05729   0.04587   0.04728   0.06073   0.13366
   0.14064   0.08582   0.05424   0.04640   0.04971   0.06411   0.09676
   0.09676   0.06411   0.04971   0.04640   0.05424   0.08582   0.14064
   0.13366   0.06073   0.04728   0.04587   0.05729   0.13085   Star   
   0.08469   0.05562   0.04574   0.04433   0.05218   0.08190   0.13222
   0.06715   0.05619   0.04631   0.04302   0.04635   0.05627   0.06728
   0.13073   0.08043   0.05075   0.04294   0.04439   0.05432   0.08347
```